# ParametricPlot problem with conformal mapping

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to use ParametricPlot to visualize w=1/z. I used:

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[1/(x + I y)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> 20, 
 AxesLabel -> {u, v}, 
 PlotLabel -> "w = \!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(z\)]\)", Frame -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Yellow, Exclusions -> None]
```

but the central region has no mesh (I know that there's a pole in z=0 so I tried Exclusions->None). How can I force ParametricPlot to draw inside the void central region?

[image]

Comment: Using `ParametricPlot`you only visualize the parameter plane x,y. Try `Plot3D` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since the mapping $w=1/z$ map the circle $|z|=r$ to the circle $|w|=1/r$, so if we want to full fill the $w$ region, we need to set $r$ to infinity,so it is impossible.

Here we set the definition region to `Disk[{0, 0}, r]` and vary `r` to demonstrate this.

```
Table[ParametricPlot[
  ReIm[1/(x + I y)], {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, r], 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}, 
  Mesh -> {Range[-1, 1, .1], Range[-1, 1, .1]}, BoundaryStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> 6, AxesLabel -> {u, v}, 
  PlotLabel -> "w = \!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(z\)]\)", 
  Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Yellow, 
  Exclusions -> None], {r, {1, 2, 4, 8}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that it's important that `PlotRange` remain fixed during this process;  otherwise, Mathematica will "helpfully" change the bounds of the plot, with the result that the hole in the middle appears to remain the same size.

Comment: Thank you very much